# Thymeleaf method to get requestURI

Tags: java, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Given the lastest Spring Boot version + few extra thymeleaf modules, the application will not generate requestURI anymore in templates. I believe it has to do with a change (https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/commit/dd01397c785d7d34049eecd67440aef52398599d) recently in the thymeleaf core. But according to SO this is the right way to do it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74922599/230638). What is the current right way to do it?

Error:

```
2023-10-13 14:44:20,158 ERROR [http-nio-8888-exec-1] [] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/helpdesk/orders/list.html]")] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.EvaluationException: Accessing member 'requestUri' is forbidden for type 'class org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext' in this expression context
```

Fragment:

```
th:action="${#ctx.springRequestContext.requestUri}"
```

POM/dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
</parent>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Temurin JDK 17

Comment: It's unclear why you want this... can you just add it to the model via the controller?  Why doesn't `@{/}` work --or something similar.

Comment: It's an existing codebase with different reasons for this minimal example. It's in fragments resused between templates, so we can't hardcode it. sometimes it's used as a returnURI param in a request, and coding it in the controller makes changing the template need changes in the controllers, which doesn't sound like a solution. Business data  coupling OK, but this is just a technicallity that's in the way I think.

Comment: Here is the way arround i'm using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74594544/getrequesturi-is-null-with-netty-and-spring-boot-3

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me with version 3.1.4 either. But if you downgrade to version 3.1.1 it will work.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a real solution. You are now stuck with technical debt and missing out on security fixes.

Comment: same constatation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466130/spring-mvc-how-do-i-get-current-url-in-thymeleaf