# Spring Boot Thymeleaf th:classappend url

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am facing problem with thymeleaf. I don't know why my class does not apply to my link in header. When user is on endpoint /about I want him to do not see about link in header, but when he is on any other endpoint I want him to see it. I tried class append, but it did not work.

header.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6">
<head>
  <title>Header</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <a sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" th:href="@{/register}">Register</a>
  <a sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" th:href="@{/login}">Login</a>
  <a sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" th:classappend="#{httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/about'} ? 'hidden' : 'show'" th:href="@{/about}">About</a>
  <a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/logYouOut}">Logout</a>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

form-style.css

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form {
    background-color: #3399ff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

form input[type="text"],
form input[type="password"],
form input[type="number"],
form input[type="submit"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 200px;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #3399ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black:
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
}
header {
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #3399ff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
    padding: 30px;
}
.show {
    display: block;
    padding: 200px;
}
```

What`s wrong there?
Thanks

Comment: Does this: [getrequesturi-is-null-with-netty-and-spring-boot-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74594544/getrequesturi-is-null-with-netty-and-spring-boot-3) answer your question?